# Javascript - Is there a difference between this.foo and this.prototype.foo

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any difference between this:

```
function Foo(){
    this.bar = function(){
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
fooObj = new Foo();
```

and this?

```
function Foo(){

}

Foo.prototype.bar = function(){
    console.log('hello');
}
fooObj = new Foo();
```

These seem to behave the same, but I don't yet have a full understanding of prototypes. Is `foo.prototype` just a way of declaring a method outside of a class?

Answer (score 7):

The first example creates a new function object for each new object created with that constructor and assigns it to the property, the second example creates a single function that each new object references.

This means that for instance for your first example

```
var fooObj1 = new Foo();
var fooObj2 = new Foo();

alert(fooObj1.bar === fooObj2.bar) //false
```

while for the second

```
alert(fooObj1.bar === fooObj2.bar) //true
```

This is because in the first example the bar properties refer to 2 seperate but identical objects, while for the second they are the same.

In general the recommendation is that functions should be declared on the prototype to preserve memory, while other objects should be declared individually, unless you want to declare a "static" object that is shared among all objects created with that constructor.

Its easier to see the distinctions with normal objects or arrays rather than functions

```
function Foo(){
    this.bar = [];
}
var fooObj1 = new Foo();
var fooObj2 = new Foo();

fooObj1.bar.push("x");
alert(fooObj2.bar) //[]
```

as opposed to:

```
function Foo(){
}

Foo.prototype.bar = []
var fooObj1 = new Foo();
var fooObj2 = new Foo();

fooObj1.bar.push("x");
alert(fooObj2.bar) //["x"]
```

Comment: They are functionally the same, meaning they will both work the same way, but @ben336 is right;  The prototype is used any time an object is created.  The bad part of option 1 is that you have a separate copy of this method in every single object... it's less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

basically, the difference is:

```
....
this.bar = function(){
        console.log('hello');
    }
....
```

means that each instance of `Foo` "class" will have its own `bar`.

```
....
Foo.prototype.bar = function(){
    console.log('hello');
}
....
```

means that all instances of `Foo` "class" will share one `bar`. Sort of static property.

Comment: This really clearred things up for me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

The bar method in the first example will not be inherited from Constructors that inherit from foo. Also, in the first example, objects created by foo will have their own unique copy of bar, while in the second example they share the same copy of bar.

When an object is created by a constructor, it gets a property called "**proto**" that points to the constructor's prototype property. "**proto**" is  a special property in JavaScript that causes the object to inherit all of the properties of the prototype object it points to.

Comment: proto is actually named two underscores + proto + two underscores. I guess I need to look up how to escape markdown . . .